# How to raise a float number to complex power in Python?

Tags: python, math

My program:

```
j = complex(0,1)
G1 = math.exp(j)
```

That is what I get:

```
TypeError: can't convert complex to float
```

What is the best way to solve this?

Comment: @Carcigenicate unfortunately returned ugly traceback

Comment: Sorry man, it works. Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `cmath` instead of `math`:

```
import cmath
j = complex(0,1)
G1 = cmath.exp(j)
```

Answer (score 1):

@OmG's way is probably the preferred way, but `**` also gives the same answer:

```
>>> j = complex(0,1)
>>> math.e ** j
(0.5403023058681398+0.8414709848078965j)
```